# Graphviz: Can't find cluster.exe in release/bin for using Cluster Tool in console

Tags: cmd, graphviz

I found this in the Graphviz Dokumentation (https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/pdf/cluster.1.pdf)

```
SYNOPSIS
 cluster[−v?] [−Ck][−ck][−ooutfile][ files]
DESCRIPTION
 cluster takes as input a graph in DOT format, finds node clusters and augments the graph with     this informa- tion. The clusters are specified by the "cluster" attribute attached to nodes; 
 cluster values are non-negative integers. cluster attempts to maximize the modularity of the clustering. If the edge attribute "weight" is defined, this will be used in computing the clustering.
```

This implies to me that I should be able to use "cluster" on a dot file and it generates the clusters. My problem is that it does not exist in the downloaded release/bin.

Does this really exist? If so where can i get it to use it in the cmd?

Comment: I didn't see it in my 2.38.0 Windows distribution either, I did see it in the Cygwin 2.40.1 version. Didn't investigate further but might be a "new"  program or a program that isn't in all distributions.

Comment: Okay good so I'm not blind. Where can I get the 2.40.1 version?

Comment: I would look at https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/

Comment: I'll do that thank you @Albert. I just assumed,  as the Dokument is singed with 2011 that the feature was a bit older.

Comment: I would expect this as well, but maybe not al distributions contain the cluster.exe (upon today I didn't hear about it either).

Answer (score 0):

the cluster.exe is only available in 2.40 builds. However a 2.40 build for windows does not exist. I dowloaded the Linux version installed in in a VM and there i can use the cluster function.